# Is there a lightweight REST client frameworks that allows parallel construction of requests?

Tags: java, rest, http, kotlin, unirest

I love [Unirest](http://unirest.io/java.html), I really do...

Unfortunately, it seems like it isn't very thread-safe.

I tried to parallelize my requests:

```
runBlocking {
    for (a in 0..9) async{
        for (b in 0..9) async{
            for (c in 0..9) async{
                if (!found) Unirest.post(targetURL)
                    .body(String.format(requestTemplate, a, b, c))
                    .asStringAsync(object : Callback<String> {...})
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and all I achieved was

```
Feb 11, 2019 11:44:51 PM org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient run
SEVERE: I/O reactor terminated abnormally
com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException: java.net.ConnectException
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper$1.failed(HttpClientHelper.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.failed(BasicFuture.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.AbstractClientExchangeHandler.failed(AbstractClientExchangeHandler.java:419)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.AbstractClientExchangeHandler.connectionRequestFailed(AbstractClientExchangeHandler.java:335)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.AbstractClientExchangeHandler.access$100(AbstractClientExchangeHandler.java:62)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.AbstractClientExchangeHandler$1.failed(AbstractClientExchangeHandler.java:378)
    at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.failed(BasicFuture.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalPoolEntryCallback.failed(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:503)
    at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.failed(BasicFuture.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.RouteSpecificPool.timeout(RouteSpecificPool.java:170)
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.requestTimeout(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:560)
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool$InternalSessionRequestCallback.timeout(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:821)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SessionRequestImpl.timeout(SessionRequestImpl.java:182)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processTimeouts(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:212)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:350)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:191)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException
    ... 10 more
```

The code runs fine without the `async`s, so I will blame the error on concurrent accesses to resources that are not meant to be concurrently accessed. (If I'm wrong about that, pray do tell.)

Are there client frameworks that are lightweight yet allow for this kind of parallelisation?

Comment: Have you explored the following? `Unirest.setAsyncHttpClient(asyncHttpClient);` and `Unirest.setConcurrency(int maxTotal, int maxPerRoute);` (where `asyncHttpClient` is `HttpAsyncClient `)

Comment: It appears you can also use this: `Unirest.post(...).someMethod(...).asJsonAsync(new Callback<JsonNode>() { //anonymous class });`